Movie about a gangster group with a black stone that emits a green light from a machine when it extends its power
I think this movie was released between 1998 and 2005.
In it, a girl is kidnapped by a gangster group. Her father plans to rescue her, with the help of his friends. At the same time, another pat of the group have a black stone. With the help of a special machine they extend the power of that black stone. They call a bad person from the underworld to show them how to do this.
The special machine extends the power of black stone. For example, it distorted one building, then a city, then a state, then a country. Whilst this process is going on, green light is released from it which makes the stone powerful.
When the father calls his girl (who was kidnapped by the gangster) and asked for her location, she told him that around her location some green light was coming out. Then her father reaches that location and at the end killed the gangster. One policeman helped them as well.

Gangster group called underworld bad person for bidding that black stone prize. - What does this mean?

While other side gangster group - different people in the same gangster group, or a different group?

That means kidnapper (gangster) group called don type of person for bidding that black stone prize, and show them demo of how to extend power of that black stone. when this process is going on than green light released from that machine..

No, gangster group is kidnapper group.. this group same  not different people group.

Do those changes make sense? I've tried to make it a little clearer.

Dude, here in India we speak different English, and also write few different  English, so may be communication gap will be here..

Agreed. And we accept questions and answers on this site knowing that. But we also need to make sure the questions are readable and useful to future users, which quite often means editing them so they are a little clearer.

Okk.. Andrew martin from next time i will try to make perfect question.

The movie is "Cradle 2 the Grave" from 2003.

A jewel thief's daughter is kidnapped after he steals a collection of prized black diamonds, which aren't at all what they seem.

Below is the official trailer :




Thanks.. IvanaMNE.. This is 100% right.. I show official trailer which provide by you..

Is this second part or just one part or movie of sequences series..??

It's one part, but there is another movie that has the same actors in the lead roles, "Exit Wounds" from 2001.
